# Replacing values in two dimensional list

Tags: python

I am trying to build a Pajek NET file for network visualization in python. My approach is to use one two dimensional list or dict as a key for a second one and either replace the values or create a new list altogether. Example input:

```
Vertices = [('1', 'test.com'), ('2', 'testb.com'), ('3', 'testc.com'), ('4', '1.1.1.1'), ('5', '2.2.2.2'), ('6', '3.3.3.3')]

matches = [('test.com', '1.1.1.1'), ('test.com', '3.3.3.3'), ('test.com', '2.2.2.2'), ('testb.com', '3.3.3.3'), ('testc.com', '3.3.3.3')]
```

Result, replacing both k and v in matches with k in Vertices. With the output list rendered as such

```
Edges = [('1', '4'), ('1', '6'), ('1', '5'), ('2', 6'), ('3', '6')]
```

Unsure about how to tackle this one. Appreciate any insight from the gurus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you chose a different data structure, it would be trivial:

```
>>> Vertices = {'test.com': '1', 'testb.com': '2', 'testc.com': '3', '1.1.1.1': '4', '2.2.2.2': '5', '3.3.3.3': '6'}
>>> matches = [('test.com', '1.1.1.1'), ('test.com', '3.3.3.3'), ('test.com', '2.2.2.2'), ('testb.com', '3.3.3.3'), ('testc.com', '3.3.3.3')] 
>>> Edges = [(Vertices[v1], Vertices[v2]) for v1,v2 in matches]
>>> Edges
[('1', '4'), ('1', '6'), ('1', '5'), ('2', '6'), ('3', '6')]
```

Using your own data structure, it gets convoluted:

```
>>> Edges = []
>>> for item in matches:
...     for vertex in Vertices:
...         if vertex[1] == item[0]:
...             i = vertex[0]
...             break
...     for vertex in Vertices:
...         if vertex[1] == item[1]:
...             j = vertex[0]
...             break
...     Edges.append((i,j))
...
>>> Edges
[('1', '4'), ('1', '6'), ('1', '5'), ('2', '6'), ('3', '6')]
```

Comment: To OP: if you want to create Tim's version of `Vertices` from your own, it's as simple as `Vertices = {v: k for k, v in Vertices}`.

Comment: Stack overflow has an uncanny way of making me feel dumb. Thank you sir